# Flutter - Align only one widget inside of a Row

Tags: flutter, alignment, row-height

I have a text that can vary in height, followed by a PopupMenuButton. I want the text to be center-aligned on the vertical axis (so that there isn't a weird white space when there's only 1 ligne of text) but the PopupMenuButton to stay in the top right corner, no matter the height of the text. Thus using crossAxisAlignement doesn't work here since all widgets are affected. Using an Align widget on the text or PopupMenuButton doesn't work and textAlign doesn't either It seems any solution must be implemented on the Row level and not in its children, which makes sense.

For now I'm using a Row to contain these 2 widgets, but I'm not so sure it is what I need if I want the behaviour mentionned before. Is there a solution for the Row, or another widget I can use for this ?

Here is the code as it stands. Thanks.

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: RichText(
        text: TextSpan(), // bunch of text in there
        )
      )
    ),
    SizedBox( // To box in the 3 dots icon (material design forces 48px otherwise)
      height: 24,
      width: 24,
      child: PopupMenuButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        onSelected: menuSelect,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
          return [
            PopupMenuItem(value: 0, child: Text('Read', textAlign: TextAlign.center,),),
            PopupMenuItem(value: 1, child: Text('Delete', textAlign: TextAlign.center,),)
          ];
        },
      ),
    )
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do it :

- Wrap your `SizedBox` with an `Align(alignment: Alignment.topRight)`
- Wrap your `Row` with an `IntrinsicHeight` so that the cross-axis
  doesn't stretch

Alternatively, you might want to look into the [Stack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liEGSeD3Zt8) widget if you're not familiar with it.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I've looked into Stack, but I figured there might have been a more elegant way to solve this, which you provided.
While it solves my problem, I am not exactly sure as to why IntrinsicHeight has this effect. Is it because it does a "speculative layout pass before the final layout phase", as described here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html ? As in, the PopupMenuButton isn't concerned by this while the RichText is, resulting in the difference ?
Thanks !

Comment: The answer is in that sentence : _This class is useful, for example, when unlimited height is available and you would like a child that would otherwise attempt to expand infinitely to instead size itself to a more reasonable height._ Here, the "more reasonable height" is the one of the tallest widget in the `Row`. I think it's basically like `Row(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min)` but for the cross axis, or like `ListView(shrinkWrap: true)`.